# Can a set of states be orthonormal, but not complete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

In this PSE question [If a basis set is complete, are the elements in it mutually orthonormal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/517417/) it was argued that if a basis set is complete, then the elements need not be mutually orthogonal (or even orthonormal). What happens if we know that a set of vectors are mutually orthonormal? Is there a way of knowing whether or not this set is complete?

Can someone also give a physical example of orthonormal sets of vectors that are not complete? For instance, I am reading that an ensemble average of an operator is defined by
$$\langle O\rangle=\sum_iw_i\langle\alpha_i|O|\alpha_i\rangle$$
where the number $w_i$ is the statistical weight, satisfying $\sum_iw_i=1$ and $w_i\ge0$, and the states $\{|\alpha_i\rangle\}$ need not be complete, but they are normalized. Does this mean that they need not be orthogonal as well?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take as the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$ and as a set of vectors the set that consists of the vector $(1,0)$ only. This is a set of orthonormal vectors, but it is not complete. It misses a second basis vector, e.g. $(0,1)$.

Comment: So, not being complete does not necessarily mean that they are not orthogonal, or am I wrong?

Comment: @schris38:  Setting aside the double negatives:  A set of vectors can be (a) mutually orthogonal, (b) a basis for the space they're a part of, (c) both, or (d) neither.  All options are possible.

Comment: Okay thanks @MichaelSeifert

Comment: +1, but a better example might have been $\mathbb{C}^3$ and the set $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. These are more obviously orthonormal but not complete.